# jQuery.inArray returning -1

Tags: jquery, return

I’ve wrote this code:

```
    $(document).on('click','.remove_email',function(event) {
        dato_in_mod=(($(event.target).text()).replace(" ",""));
        mail_address.splice((jQuery.inArray(dato_in_mod,mail_address)),1);
        $('#email_add').val(mail_address);
    })
```

but there is a problem. The spliciing in array doesn’t work because, as I see in console.log, jQuery.inArray return -1. I tried also adding “”:

```
$(document).on('click','.remove_email',function(event) {
        dato_in_mod=(($(event.target).text()).replace(" ",""));
        mail_address.splice((jQuery.inArray(‘“‘+dato_in_mod+’"',mail_address)),1);
        $('#email_add').val(mail_address);
    })
```

Could anyone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inArray` will only return `-1` if the value isn't in the array. You've said you're sure the value is in the array, but if `inArray` is returning `-1`, it *isn't*. [`inArray` isn't broken](http://pragmatictips.com/26). So the question is: What's *different* about the value in the array vs. the value in `dato_in_mod`?

My guess is that it has one or more spaces at the end in one place or the other. Your code that removes spaces

```
dato_in_mod=(($(event.target).text()).replace(" ",""));
```

only removes the **first** space in the string. If there is more than one, the remaining ones are left in the string. Trailing spaces on a string can be very hard to see, particularly via `console.log`. Use the debugger built into your browser to stop the code on the `inArray` line and then inspect the `dato_in_mod` and `mail_address` variables with the debugger. You'll probably find extra spaces on one or the other, making them not match.

To remove *all* spaces from a string, change `.replace(" ","")` to `.replace(/ /g,"")`:

```
dato_in_mod=(($(event.target).text()).replace(/ /g,""));
```

---

Side note: You don't need `()` around a single expression. These two lines are identical once compiled/interpreted:

```
dato_in_mod=(($(event.target).text()).replace(/ /g,""));
dato_in_mod=$(event.target).text().replace(/ /g,"");
```

---

Side note 2: It's probably a good idea to check the index you get back from `inArray` before passing it to `splice`:

```
var index = jQuery.inArray(dato_in_mod, mail_address);
if (index >= 0) {
    mail_address.splice(index, 1);
}
```

If you don't, and the value isn't in the array, `splice` will interpret the negative number as an offset from the end of the array, and remove the wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I see a misspelling.  You are using `data_in_mod` in one place and `dato_in_mod` in the other.  Those two must obviously be the same spelling.

---

`jQuery.inArray()` returns `-1` when the object you are searching for is not found in the array you are searching within or if you don't have the arguments correct.  So, either `dato_in_mod` is not being found in an array named `mail_address` or you have those arguments wrong.

You can debug your own code by adding `console.log()` statements to output the values of `dato_in_mod` and `mail_address` so you can see if they are what you expect or not and that should also show you why `dato_in_mod` is not being found.

If you could back up and explain what you are trying to actually accomplish upon your `click` event, we could probably offer a much better way of doing it.

Comment: I’ve a form with a text-field for the email address and users could add more than one email address. When an user add an address it is pushed in the array; I would give the possibility to the user to remove the address before submitting the form..so this is the goal of the click event on the button..

Comment: @Joe - do a `console.log(data_in_mod)` after you populate that variable and see exactly what it is.  It is probably not what you think.  This is basic debugging technique.

Comment: I execute: ‘ console.log(dato_in_mod);
   console.log(mail_address);
   pos=jQuery.inArray(dato_in_mod,mail_address); 
   console.log(pos);’ and this is the result.. 'email@email244.it  
["email@email1.it", "email@email244.it"]
-1'

Comment: @Joe - you are using different spellings with `data_in_mod` in one place and `dato_in_mod` in the other.  Those must match.

Comment: Sorry I make a mistake in the question; The variable is dato_in_mod everywhere, I’m sorry ;)

Comment: @Joe - There is some difference (perhaps you don't see a space in the `console.log()` output).   You can see here in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5y2V4/) that if the data is really as you say, then `jQuery.inArray(data_in_mod, mail_address)` finds it.  Computers don't lie.  If it says the value isn't in the array, then it isn't in the array.  You need to examine both values more closely and find out why they don't match.